# How to recreate a merge destroyed by a git rebase

Tags: git, merge, rebase

My git history was

```
A-B---D-------H-I-J
   \         /
    C---E-F-G
```

when I decided to do a `git rebase -i A` to move commit `F` right after commit `B`.

Now I got

```
A-B-----------F-C-D-E-F-G-I-J
   \
    C---E---G
```

which is not what I wanted.

How can I get to

```
A-B-F-D-------H-I-J
   \         /
    C---E---G
```

and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you please describe the original history and your wanted history more clearly? It looks like you have two branches?

Comment: Sorry, the graph in the phone looks odd but in computer it's okay. So forget my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out your reflog using

```
git reflog
```

And should see lines like

```
b9778dc HEAD@{x}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
92a366c HEAD@{y}: merge origin/master: Recursive
```

Each of these lines shows when your `HEAD` was moved (by a `commit`, a `merge`, a `rebase` etc.). You can search for the commit `J` in there. Obviously you won't know the SHA1 of the commit, so you need to guess a little. It was two commits after a merge, so it might look like

```
[...]
1e53f16 HEAD@{x}: commit: J commit message
f8577d2 HEAD@{y}: commit: I commit message
e8969e2 HEAD@{z}: merge e8969e2: Recursive
```

If you then do e.g.

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{x}
```

you should end up with `HEAD` on `J` and your old graph restored.

Note that picking the wrong commit will not break things. None of the commits are deleted and each of those `git reset`s will simply add another line to the reflog:

```
1e53f16 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{x}
[...]
1e53f16 HEAD@{x+1}: commit: J commit message
f8577d2 HEAD@{y+1}: commit: I commit message
e8969e2 HEAD@{z+1}: merge e8969e2: Recursive
```

Meaning

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

will undo the last move you did.

Comment: This will get me back. But how to get to the intended result?

Comment: You should open another question for this. Also, do the cherry picking thing ElpieKay suggested. Rebasing will not solve this (it cannot create merges and you cannot split-rebase into two branches).

Answer (score 0):

Since `git rebase` is a bit tricky, I prefer `git cherry-pick`.

```
1.git checkout -b new_branch

2.git reset B --hard

A-B->new_branch HEAD

3.git cherry-pick F D

A-B-F'-D'->new_branch HEAD

4.git checkout -b side_branch E

A-B-F'-D'->new_branch
  \
   C-E->side_branch HEAD

5.git cherry-pick G

A-B-F'-D'->new_branch
  \
   C-E-G'->side_branch HEAD

6.git checkout new_branch

A-B-F'-D'->new_branch HEAD
  \
   C-E-G'->side_branch

7.git merge side_branch

A-B-F'-D'---H'->new_branch HEAD
  \        / 
   C-E-----G'->side_branch

8.git cherry-pick I J

A-B-F'-D'---H'-I'-J'->new_branch HEAD
  \        / 
   C-E-----G'->side_branch
```

Now new_branch is what you want, you could delete your previous branch and rename new_branch or just keep both.

Comment: Cherry-picking your way to the perfect commit history is always the last resort. I'd like to know if it is possible with rebase.

Comment: @Chaos_99 cherry-pick is the most straightforward and clearest and simplest